# Форма сдвигает заголовок?

Tags: html, css

Д В С!)
У меня такая проблема есть такая форма вот

```
<span class="frendsend"><form action='coalition.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>'      method='post'>
тут еще есть скрытые поля в форме..
<a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();">Войти</a></form>
<a href='#'>Бла бла бла</a><br><br>
<a href='my_coalitions.php'>БЛа бла</a><br><br></span>
```

и проблема в том что форма сдвигает нижние 2 ссылки!
скажите можно ли какнибудь решить это к примеру вынести кнопку Субмит за пределы формы или еще чтонибудь??

Comment: Ну блин...берешь и выносишь, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не нравится, что форма делает перенос строки, то поставь у нее в стиле: `display: inline`

```
<span class="frendsend"><form action='coalition.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>'      method='post' style='display: inline;'>
тут еще есть скрытые поля в форме..
<a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();">Войти</a></form>
<a href='#'>Бла бла бла</a><br><br>
<a href='my_coalitions.php'>БЛа бла</a><br><br></span>
```

---

Если не нравится что кнопка `Войти` находится выше двух других ссылок, можно просто перенести ее ниже твоих ссылок:

```
<span class="frendsend"><form action='coalition.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>'      method='post' style='display: inline;'>
тут еще есть скрытые поля в форме..
<a href='#'>Бла бла бла</a><br><br>
<a href='my_coalitions.php'>БЛа бла</a><br><br>
<a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();">Войти</a></form></span>
```

хотя тут, судя по скрипту тебе тоже необязательно держать ссылку внутри формы, т.к. ты глобально ищешь форму, и жмешь на sumbit

Comment: еще вопрос - у меня на стрнице несколько форм и обработчики этих форм находятся там же все в одном скрипте - как можно присвоить кнопкам субмит айдишники что бы они давили на нужный обработчик??

Comment: Например найти элемент по id:

    document.getElementById('formId_1')

У формы надо поставить соответственно id:

    <span class="frendsend"><form action='coalition.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>'      method='post' style='display: inline;' id="formId_1">
    тут еще есть скрытые поля в форме..
    <a href='#'>Бла бла бла</a><br><br>
    <a href='my_coalitions.php'>БЛа бла</a><br><br>
    <a href="javascript: document.getElementById('formId_1').submit();">Войти</a>       </form></span>

Comment: А вообще, в href лучше не писать javascript, если вы пишете чистым JavaScript (не используя всяких jQuery), то лучше так:

    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formId_1').submit(); return false;">Войти</a>